# I get an error "Trying to get property 'perbaikan' of non-object" when looping data from hasMany table

Tags: laravel-5, relationship, one-to-many

I geeting an error Trying to get property 'perbaikan' of non-object. Please help me to resolve my problem.

```html
My Perbaikan model
public function tagihan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tagihan', 'id_tagihan');
    }

My Tagihan model
  public function perbaikan()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Perbaikan');
    }

My controller
public function report(Tagihan $tagihan)
{
   return view('tagihan.report', compact('tagihan'));
}

My view blade
<tbody>
   <?php $no = 0;?>
   @foreach ($tagihan as $data)
   @foreach ($data->perbaikan as $row)
   <?php $no++ ;?>
     <tr>
         <td>{{ $no }}</td>
         <td>{{ $row -> nomor_dokumen }}</td>
         <td>{{ $row -> kulkas -> nomor_asset  }}</td>
         <td>{{ $row -> tipepekerjaan -> kode_tipe_pekerjaan }}</td>
         <td>{{ $row -> tanggal_perbaikan }}</td>
     </tr>
   @endforeach
   @endforeach
 </tbody>
```

dd($tagihan)

```html
Tagihan {#337 ▼
  #primaryKey: "id_tagihan"
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "tagihans"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:5 [▼
    "id_tagihan" => 1
    "nomor_dokumen" => "A00001919191"
    "periode_tagihan" => "Januari"
    "created_at" => "2019-02-05 08:26:00"
    "updated_at" => "2019-02-05 08:26:00"
  ]
  #original: array:5 [▼
    "id_tagihan" => 1
    "nomor_dokumen" => "A00001919191"
    "periode_tagihan" => "Januari"
    "created_at" => "2019-02-05 08:26:00"
    "updated_at" => "2019-02-05 08:26:00"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

```html
My perbaikans table
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('perbaikans', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_perbaikan');
            $table->string('nomor_dokumen_perbaikan', 25)->unique();
            $table->integer('id_tagihan')->unsigned();
            $table->string('teknisi', 30);
            $table->date('tanggal_perbaikan');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('id_tagihan)->references('id_tagihan')->on('tagihans');
        });
    }

My tagihans table
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tagihans', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_tagihan');
            $table->string('nomor_dokumen', 25);
            $table->string('periode_tagihan', 20);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I have tried to get all data from hasMany table, it works fine, but I don't want all data from the table. I only want to retrieve data based on the id from belongsTo table

I get error with message "Trying to get property 'perbaikan' of non-object"

Comment: What is the contents of `$tagihan` ? it seems like `@foreach ($tagihan->perbaikan as $row)` is causing the error and maybe should be `@foreach ($data->perbaikan as $row)` but this depends on the structure. Cam you update the question with the output of `dd($tagihan)`

Comment: Sorry that's my typo. I changed it, but I still get an error

Comment: is the code currently in your question the updated code ? if not can you make it so its the updated code

Comment: yes, I have changed it

Comment: It seems your `$tagihan` does not have any relations. are you sure the data in your database is correct ? maybe you can show the corresponding rows in the tables?

Comment: I have update my question and add my structure table

Comment: i think you need to add `protected $primaryKey = 'id_tagihan'` in your Tagihan model. Are the id's referencing your tagihan correct in the perbaikans table ?

Comment: of course I have added $primaryKey = 'id_tagihan' in my table. Yes sir, very very corectly.

Comment: Ahh sorry i overlooked a change. you are looping trough $tagihan but this is not necessary  remove  `@foreach ($tagihan as $data)` and change the line below to
   `@foreach ($tagihan ->perbaikan as $row)` also remove 1 `@endforeach`

Comment: i think i found the answer let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping trough `$tagihan` but this is not necessary

**change:**

```php
   @foreach ($tagihan as $data)
   @foreach ($data->perbaikan as $row)
```

**To:**

```php
   @foreach ($tagihan->perbaikan as $row)
```

and remove one of the `@endforeach`

Comment: work sir, but I only get 1 data from the perbaikans table, even though I have 2 data from perbaikans table with id_tagihan : 1

Comment: This seems strange are you overwriting any date in the loop ? what is the output of `dd($data->perbaikan)` it should be a collection of how many items you have attached to the `$tagihan`

Comment: my problem is solved, after dd () I only have 1 data array. then I tried to change my Tagihan model 
form :   return $this->hasMany('App\Perbaikan');
to :  return $this->hasMany('App\Perbaikan', 'id_tagihan');

Comment: I don't know what happened, can you explain to me what my mistake was

Comment: You where performing an extra loop so you where going through all the Perbaikans and then again looking for Perbaikans  which where not there. So i removed one of these loops for you